# scalatest and SBT issue -- Class is not an accessible org.scalatest.Suite

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

Revision 5 of my code has an error when running the tests using SBT:

https://www.assembla.com/code/opyate-scala-graph-fork-sbt/subversion/changesets/5

I've searched the Interwebs for "Class is not an accessible org.scalatest.Suite", [but only get results to that message in the scalatest framework code](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Class%20is%20not%20an%20accessible%20org.scalatest.Suite%22).

Please help me figure out what wrong and if it's a dependency version issue, a compatibility issue, or if the tests are just coded incorrectly.

---

The details are (one example):

**Suites**

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TDegreeRootTest
  extends Suites(
      new TDegree[immutable.Graph](immutable.Graph),
      new TDegree[  mutable.Graph](  mutable.Graph))
  with ShouldMatchers
{
}
```

**Test class**

```
class TDegree[+CC[N,E[X] <: EdgeLikeIn[X]] <: Graph[N,E] with GraphLike[N,E,CC[N,E]]]
    (val factory: GraphCompanion[CC])
    extends Suite
    with    ShouldMatchers
{ ... }
```

**The exception**

```
[error] Could not run test scalax.collection.TDegree:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    Class is not an accessible org.scalatest.Suite:
      scalax.collection.TDegree
```

**ScalaTest code that throws exception**

The following needs to hold `true` for `clazz` an instance of my `TDegree`:

```
classOf[Suite].isAssignableFrom(clazz) &&
    Modifier.isPublic(clazz.getModifiers) &&
    !Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers) &&
    Modifier.isPublic(clazz.getConstructor(emptyClassArray: _*).getModifiers)
```

*It requires a no-argument constructor, which I don't have.*

I guess the question now becomes "How do I get my test classes to run with ScalaTest if my classes do not have a non-argument constructor?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that means is that sbt is discovering and handing to ScalaTest a class that is not an accessible suite. That probably means it is package access. If it is public, make sure it has a public no-arg constructor. I'll look at the diffs real quick to see if I can see the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I'll also update my question with the actual detail once it's obvious.

Comment: BTW, this has always been a problem -- I've only recently migrated that code to use SBT.

Comment: How was it a problem before. That may be an important clue. I just double checked the code causing that exception, and it just checks to make sure the class sbt is passing is a subclass of org.scalatest.Suite, is public, non-abstract, and has a public-no-arg constructor. The only other thing that pops into mind is, if you're doing something interesting with class loaders, such that org.scalatest.Suite is being loaded by two different class loaders, then this might fail for that reason too. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: What I meant by "always been a problem" is that the code has until recently been compiled and tested per-class on the command-line (no Ant, Maven, SBT), so I've literally just recently tried to make it all work with SBT. Thanks for the suggestions -- I'll take another look.